# React Modal and Tooltip issue when using Portal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, click, tooltip, portal

I have a simple Modal component and a simple Tooltip component. Both of them can be opened by clicking on the triggering button and dismissed by clicking outside. To detect clicking outside, I use this simple hook:

```
const useClickAway = (
  ref: Ref,
  condition: boolean,
  handler: Handler
): void => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (e: Event) => {
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(e.target as Node)) {
        return;
      }
      handler(e);
    };
    if (condition) {
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', listener);
      document.addEventListener('touchend', listener);
    }
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', listener);
        document.removeEventListener('touchend', listener);
    };
  }, [ref, handler, condition]);
};
```

And this is how I use it:

```
/*
* ref - reference to the modal container
* isOpen - The modal state.
* handleClose - Handler that closes the modal.
*/
useClickAway(ref, isOpen, handleClose)
```

It has been working fine so far, but the issue appeared when I try to render my tooltip (which uses Portal to render it into the body element, instead of the react tree) inside this Modal.

When I open the modal and then open the tooltip inside it, clicking on the tooltip is causing the modal to close. Because clicking on the tooltip is considered as clicking outside for the Modal.

Can anyone provide clean solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can take advantage of `forwardRef` to pass a `ref` that is defined in the `Modal` `Tooltip` shared parent.

Here is how I would do it:

First, I would re-write both `Tooltip` and `Modal` to accept an optional external prop `ref`. such as:

```
const Tooltip = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const tooltipLocalRef = useRef(null);
  const tooltipRef = ref || tooltipLocalRef;

  //
});

// usage:
const tooltipRef = useRef(null);
<Tooltip ref={tooltipRef} anotherProps={someValue} />
```

Same goes for `Modal` component, but, in addition to the ref that we'll use for the Modal itself, we'll also send the `tooltipRef` as an extra prop.

```
const tooltipRef = useRef(null);
const modalRef = useRef(null);


<Tooltip ref={tooltipRef} anotherProp={someValue} />
<Modal ref={modalRef} tooltipRef={tooltipRef} anotherProp={someValue} />
```

By doing that, I believe we can check against the click outside the modal and make an exception for when that target is within the `tooltipRef.current` Node.

An extra work on the modal `handleClose` handler:

```
function handleClose(e) {
      if (!props.tooltipRef.current || props.tooltipRef.current.contains(e.target as Node)) {
        return;
      }
      setModalOpen(false)
}
```

I haven't tested that, let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Thanks @Sultan H. for you answer. I understand what you are saying and that should work fine, but I don't like this solution. If I want to render for example menu or something like that inside the Modal, I will have to add another ref and make another exception for that to work.

Comment: I will wait for the cleaner solution, and if nothing comes up, I'll just use the event.stopPropagation() on the tooltip wrapper element.

Comment: You're right about that, I honestly use `e.stopPropagtion` and it's not causing any up normality so far. both of the modal and tooltip components I have are rendered with Portal as well.